# only onChange and value for current input in a mapped array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I simply have an array of mapped inputs. I want to onChange the value only for the current input using useState. doing it the normal way changes the input for every input in the mapped array which is what I don't want.

example of code -

```
const [text, setText] = useState("");

comments.map((c) => (
  <Row key={c._id}>
    <Form
      onSubmit={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        addComment(comment._id, { text });
        setText("");
      }}
    >
      <InputGroup className="mb-3">
        <FormControl
          placeholder="add a comment"
          aria-label="add a comment"
          aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default"
          value={text}
          onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
        />
      </InputGroup>
    </Form>
  </Row>
));
```

This current way i'm going to change every text value for all inputs mapped which is wrong.

Apologies for simple question I couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use array instead of string for the text state, because you have state for each comment

```
const [text, setText] = useState(new Array(comments.length));

comments.map((c,i) => (
  <Row key={c._id}>
    <Form
      onSubmit={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        addComment(comment._id, { text });
        setText(new Array(comments.length));
      }}
    >
      <InputGroup className="mb-3">
        <FormControl
          placeholder="add a comment"
          aria-label="add a comment"
          aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default"
          value={text[i]}
          onChange={(e) => {
              const newText = [...text];
              newText[i] = e.target.value;
              setText(newText);
          }}
        />
      </InputGroup>
    </Form>
  </Row>
));
```

Since the state is array now you need to set the value to `text[i]` and when you change the state you need to change the text at the `i` element

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change the state to contain an *array* of text strings somewhere, not just a single string. Then use the index of the element being iterated over to identify what value to set and what index to change onchange.

Most elegant solution I think would be to change the `comments` objects to contain `text` properties as well, eg:

```
{
  _id: 'somekey',
  text: ''
  // ...
}
```

and then map over them:

```
const setCommentText = (text, i) => setComments(
  comments.map(
    (comment, i) => comment !== i ? comment : { ...comment, text }
  )
);
```

```
comments.map((c, i) => (
  <Row key={c._id}>
    <Form onSubmit={e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      addComment(comment._id, {c.text});
      setCommentText('', i);
    }}>
      <InputGroup className="mb-3" >
        <FormControl
          placeholder="add a comment"
          aria-label="add a comment"
          aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default"
          value={c.text}
          onChange={e => setCommentText(e.target.value, i)}
        />
      </InputGroup>
    </Form>
  </Row>
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState([]);

const updateValue = (value, index) => {

  const newInputValues = [... inputValues];
  newInputValues[index] = value
  setInputValues(newInputValues);

}



comments.map((c, index) => (
  <Row key={c._id}>
    ....
      <InputGroup className="mb-3">
        <FormControl
          .......
          value={inputValues[index] || ""}
          onChange={(e) => setInputValues(e.target.value)}
        />
      </InputGroup>
    </Form>
  </Row>
));
```